# More thoughts on if a entire function has at least one coefficient of the Taylor series being real

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, complex-numbers, power-series, entire-functions

I have asked a question few days ago:

[Entire function where at each $a \in \Bbb C$, at least one coefficient of the Taylor series at $a$ is real](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4245888/entire-function-where-at-each-a-in-bbb-c-at-least-one-coefficient-of-the-ta)

The question is:

> Let $f:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. Suppose that for each $a\in \mathbb{C}$ at least one coefficient of the Taylor's series $f$ about $a$ is **real**. Then, prove $f$ being a polynomial?

Thanks for @MartinR and @Conrad for their excellent explanation.

Today, I was reviewing the proofs. I recall that the Liouville's Theorem stated that is $f$ is a bounded entire function, then $f$ is a constant.

And because being a polynomial implies that there is some $N$ such that for all $k>N$, the derivatives are $f^{(k)}(z)=0$.

I am wondering if there is a way to prove the question with using the Liouville's Theorem.

Does anyone can help me figure it out?

Comment: The above statement holds for holomorphic functions $f: D \to \Bbb C$ defined on an arbitrary (connected) domain $D \subset \Bbb D$. On the other hand, Liouville's theorem is specifically for holomorphic functions defined in the entire plane. Therefore I find it unlikely that Liouville is of use here. (It is difficult though to prove that a certain technique can *not* be used in a proof.)

Comment: Interesting, is any famous papers is about proving a theorem cannot be used in a proof? Just curious. Maybe this is a good question to ask. LOL

Comment: I have no idea ...